# c++ std::this_thread::sleep_for compiler error (clang)

Tags: c++, clang++

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
```

Compiled with : `clang++ main.cpp -o main.exe -g -std=c++1z --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32`

Give me this error:

```
C:\Users\this_\AppData\Local\Temp\main-124cc2.o: In function `void std::this_thread::sleep_for<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> >(std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1ll, 1000ll> > const&)':
C:\mingw-w64\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\6.2.0\include\c++/thread:322: undefined reference to `nanosleep'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Whats happening?

Comment: I think, you need to add `-lpthread` for it to work.

Comment: That is a _linker_ error, not a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, it solved with `-pthread`
Strange that I don´t remember using this compiler option before...

Answer (score 0):

`using std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000))‌​;` instead.